# Not able to inject $timeout into the controller in angularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am new to `Angular JS`. Currently developing a game. One of the needs is to call a function on timeout. On doing research I see that there is `$timeout` provided by `AngularJS` and I have to inject `$timeout` into the controller and I am trying to do that. But for some reason I'm not sure of it doesn't seem to work! Or I don't know how to debug?

```
 var ObstacleApp = angular.module('ObstacleApp', [])
 .controller('GameCtrl',function($scope,$timeout,game) {
 $scope.game = game;
 });

 ObstacleApp.factory('game', function() {
 var tileNames = ['true', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'true','true','true','false','true','true','true','false','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true'];

 return new Game(tileNames);
 });


  function Game(tileNames)
  {
     // omitted code

     this.showOnClick = function()
     {
       // omitted code

       $timeout(callOnTimeout,6000);
     }
  }
```

**Edit**:
I have made the changes mentioned by @STEVER - yet it seems to not work.
When I `Inspect` the console I see

```
Error: Unknown provider: $timeoutProvider <- $timeout
at Error (native)
at file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2492:15
at Object.getService [as get] (file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2620:39)
at file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2497:45
at getService (file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2620:39)
at invoke (file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2650:13)
at Object.instantiate (file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:2677:23)
at file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:4354:24
at file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:3986:17
at forEach (file:///home/rakshith/Desktop/Obstaclegame/lib/angular/angular.js:118:20)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5240
```

Comment: where `Game` function belongs?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject `$timeout` into your factory like so:

```
ObstacleApp.factory('game', function($timeout) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ObstacleApp.factory('game', function($timeout) {
    //...
    return new Game(tileNames, $timeout);
 });


  function Game(tileNames, $timeout)
  {
     // omitted code

     this.showOnClick = function()
     {
       // omitted code

       $timeout(callOnTimeout,6000);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Made these changes. Yet there seems to be some error. I have edited my question - that contains the error that I see on the console.